# Export Report data using a specific Date format?

Tags: reporting, date

I have two date formats in my Org. We have to use it that way, but I would like to be able to convert to one or another when exporting to xls.

Is there a way to tell SF to create export in specific date format?

Comment: I am not sure if there is such option in salesforce but you can create a formula field to convert one date format to another and use that field on the report so that you have everything in one date format for exporting.

Comment: That would work, prior to trying how can I isolate only one format to convert, while the correct one would stay unchanged?

Comment: Are you saying users are entering dates in different format in the same field? What is the type of the field?

Comment: Managers are entering dates but based on county we have ddmmyy or mmddyy

Comment: What is the type of the field? I believe it is text but please confirm.

Comment: We are using date as object type

Comment: if it is date type, how are users entering Dec 31,2016 date in mmddyy or ddmmyy..I believe they receive errors when entering these kind of dates. Also please note, salesforce internally stores all dates in only one format, just because users are entering dates in different format, does not mean date is stored as-is.

Comment: To illustrate what would happen, if user enters date in ddmmyyyy format..Please see this screenshot. http://imgur.com/a/AN1pu

Comment: Fixed - they have done batch upload prior my arrival - that was messing up whole thing.